# cocoa: which class in cocoa is similar to UIManagedDocument?

Tags: cocoa

I can get a managedContext by UIManagedDocument, I'm wondering whether there exists NSManagedDocument which just like UIManagedDocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `NSPersistentDocument`.

Apple [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPersistentDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html).